# jquery tooltip goes off screen need a way to prevent it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-tooltip

**CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#Box10_main').hover(function(){
        //mouse enters
        $("#tool_10").css("display", "block");
    }, function(){
        //mouse leaves
        $("#tool_10").css("display", "none");
    });    
        position: {
            viewport: $(window);
        };
    $(document).mousemove(function(event){
        var mx = event.pageX+15;
        var my = event.pageY+15;
        $("#tool_10").css("left", mx + "px").css("top", my + "px");
    });
});
```

how could I get the tooltips to stay inside the window? and i have looked around for an answer which was `position: { viewport: $(window) }` but i have no clue on where to place this in the code

Comment: what do you mean? i just joined so i'm not quite sure

Comment: Add your html/css in the question or you can create a live demo on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9c7fk/    there

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to add viewport or anything, just update this in your css

```
#tool_1, #tool_2, #tool_3, #tool_4, #tool_5, #tool_6, #tool_7, #tool_8, #tool_9, #tool_10 {
   width: 300px; 
}
```

to

```
#tool_1, #tool_2, #tool_3, #tool_4, #tool_5, #tool_6, #tool_7, #tool_8, #tool_9, #tool_10 {
  width: auto;
}
```

It will automatically wrap it and if you want to restrict it to some width just add

```
max-width: 300px;
```

So final css changes are

```
#tool_1, #tool_2, #tool_3, #tool_4, #tool_5, #tool_6, #tool_7, #tool_8, #tool_9, #tool_10 {
      width: auto;
      max-width: 300px;
    }
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/9c7fk/2/

Comment: it didn't work as i meant the hover over effect goes off the edge of the window (the tooltip) i'm not sure how to add a viewport to the jquery code but i think thats what needs to be done, any idea on how it would be possible to do so?

Comment: I didn't understand the hover effect goes off the edge of window check http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/9c7fk/3/ i have added border to tooltip, it stays within the window. Can you explain or add a image of what you want

Comment: did you meant to say vertically rather than horizontally?

Comment: http://s14.postimg.org/rkuyce6dt/Untitled.png   that image shows the hover over tooltip going off the window, i have been searching for an answer which has been adding a viewport but i'm not sure on how to add viewports to the jquery code, each block of code like the one i first posted needs a viewport so once i hover over an image that is close to the edge of the window it will not go off the edge and appear on the other side of the mouse if you get what i mean

Comment: You can refer this http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex5/dhtmltooltip.htm could not find a way to insert viewport.